# Overflow:hidden not working on mobile device browsers. So not able to block background body scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to block body scroll when popup is open on mobile devices. 
I'm using overflowY:hidden to body in my webpage, it works well in Chrome browser emulators but not in mobile device browsers. Please anyone can help?

**Popup Open Code :-**

```
  $("body").on("click touchstart", ".btn-order-delivery", function () {
        mParticleLogEventOther('Catering Order - Delivery');
        $.magnificPopup.close();
        $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: $(this).attr("href"),
                type: "inline",
            },
            closeOnBgClick: false
        });
        if ($('body').hasClass('iphone') || $('body').hasClass('android')) {
            $('body').css('overflowY', 'hidden');
        }
    });
```

**Popup Close Code :-**

```
$('body').on('click touchstart', '.delivery-close', function (e) {
        if ($('body').hasClass('iphone') || $('body').hasClass('android')) {
            $('body').css('overflowY', 'auto');
        }
        mParticleLogEventOther('Delivery - close overlay');
    });
```

**HTML code :-** 
Inside the `<head>` I have used below meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, , height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply `overflow: hidden;` to both `html` and `body` tags when popup is open.

Comment: I applied overflow: hidden; to both html and body tags but still It's not working for me. Kindly help me to fix this issue